# EB CLI requires the 'docker' Python package

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ebcli

I'm not sure if this is Docker, the Elastick Beanstalk, or docker image issue related, but my problem is that I'm running the command `eb local run` to start the local environment alongside with docker.

#### Expected behavior

The command runs seamlessly

#### Actual behavior

> ERROR: DockerVersionError - Your local host has the 'docker-py' version 1.10.6 Python package installed on it.
>   When you run a Multicontainer Docker application locally, the EB CLI requires the 'docker' Python package.
>
> To fix this error:
>   Be sure that no applications on your local host require 'docker-py', and then run this command:
>
> pip uninstall docker-py
>
> The EB CLI will install 'docker' the next time you run it.

[image]
`$ eb --version` : EB CLI 3.12.2 (Python 2.7.1)

`$ docker -v` : Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

Comment: I also got this error.

Comment: It's working now, just downgrade the EB CLI to 3.12.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch multi-container Dockers using `eb local run`, you need to have uninstalled `docker-py`, and installed `docker`

As the error message indicates:

1. perform `pip uninstall docker-py` ** **if you don't need it** **.
2. run `pip install "docker>=2.6.0,<2.7"` immediately after

`docker` and `docker-py` cannot coexist. [These](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/releases/tag/2.0.0) release notes highlight the change in the package name. [These](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/releases/tag/2.0.2) release notes allude to the breakage the change in package name caused.

Not to be confused with Docker, the engine/client, [`docker-py`/`docker`](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) is a Python wrapper around the Docker client which the EBCLI relies on.

Comment: It's not clear where I should do this change. On the docker image?

Comment: No, the `host` or wherever you are running `eb local run`.